# Why i can't create this directory name ? Getting: The given path's format is not supported

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

```
List<string> countryPaths = new List<string>();
        private void CreateCountryDateTimeDirectories(List<string> urls)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < countriesNames.Count(); i++)
            {
                string pathDateTime = urls[0].Substring(48, 12);
                string pathDateTimeLast = urls[urls.Count - 1].Substring(48, 12);
                var d = DateTime.ParseExact(pathDateTime, "yyyyMMddHHmm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                var e = DateTime.ParseExact(pathDateTimeLast, "yyyyMMddHHmm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                string country = countriesNames[i].Substring(15);
                string countryPath = countriesMainPath + "\\" + country + "\\" + "[" + d + "---" + e + "]";
                if (!Directory.Exists(countryPath))
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(countryPath);
                }
                countryPaths.Add(countryPath);
            }
        }
```

On the line

```
Directory.CreateDirectory(countryPath);
```

I'm getting: The given path's format is not supported

For example the first directory it's trying to create and give the exception:

C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\s\s\Countries\Europe\[19/01/2017 19:15:00---19/01/2017 21:30:00]

I guess the problem is the last part: [19/01/2017 19:15:00---19/01/2017 21:30:00]
Then how can i create a directory like that or something like that ? with the date and time range ?

Comment: It contains a colon. You can't put colons in file/directory names.

Comment: As others already noted, the `:` is not allowed. You can get a list of all invalid chars via [`Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.io.path.getinvalidfilenamechars(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't have `:`s anywhere in a path (other than a drive letter).

And the `/`s will become directory separators, which is not what you want.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid trouble, replace all specific characters by _ Maybe it won't be as nice but it will be much more safe

following characters are disallowed (at least on windows)

```
/\:*?"<>|
```

Comment: I tried nothing is working. string countryPath = countriesMainPath + "\\" + country + "\\" + "_" + d + "___" + e + "_"; same exception. Maybe the date and time it self make the problem the variables 'd' and 'e' ?